# Archimedean property of reals

Tags: real-analysis

I am not certain what the Archimedean property of the reals really states. [Apostol](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201002884) says that $\forall r\in \mathbb{R}\exists n\in \mathbb{Z^+}(r<n)$. Can I consistently replace $<$ by $\leq$ in the above definition, as I see done [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-archimedean-property)? Are there any subtleties lurking around in the equality?

Comment: If $n\ge r$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ then $n+1>r$ and $n+1\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: The Archimedian property says that zero is the only infinitesimal of R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with that. Clearly, Apostol's definition implies the other. On the other hand, suppose the other definition holds. Then $n+1$ is also a positive integer, and $r<n+1,$ so Apostol's definition holds.

Comment: Apostol's definition implies the other in the trivial sense that $A\Rightarrow A or B$?

Comment: That's exactly right.